# Node js - Error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: javascript, node.js, tedious

I'm working with node and i'm having this error but this only happens sometimes.
But this time is permanent.

My config:

```
    var mssql = require("mssql");
var config =
{
  user: "user",
  password: "pass",
  server: "devsv",
  database: "db"
}

var db = new mssql.Connection(config);

db.connect(function(err)
{
    console.log(err);
});

module.exports = db;
```

Erro:

```
    { ConnectionError: Failed to connect to devsv:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND devsv devsv:1433
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Projects/p1/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js:378:25)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:290:19)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.socketError (/Users/user/Projects/p1/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:531:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at connectErrorNT (net.js:1025:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
  name: 'ConnectionError',
  message: 'Failed to connect to devsv:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND devsv devsv:1433',
  code: 'ESOCKET' }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is ms sql server running on port 1433 right now?

Answer (score 0):

`ENOTFOUND` typically means the hostname could not be resolved to an address.

There are many possible causes, including:

- You may need to add `devsv` to your local hostname resolution configuration (e.g., add an entry for it to `/etc/hosts`).
- Maybe your default domain is not set properly on your server.
- Maybe you have a typo in the hostname and it is not supposed to be `devsv` but something else.

The above is not an exhaustive list, but those are likely causes.